# How to update a marker's location on google map without having to refresh entire map?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, geolocation, google-api

I am trying to display the current location on google map every 3 sec.It technically works, however the entire map refreshes every 3 seconds too. How can I display the current location smoothly on the map without having to refresh the entire map ( unless necessary such as when the agent goes off the map and current location no longer exist on the map)?

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo">It displays your current location:</p>

<div id="mapholder"></div>
<div id="time"></div>

<script>

window.onload =   getLocation();

var x = document.getElementById("demo");
var displayTime = document.getElementById("time");
function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {

    //    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition,showError);

        setInterval(function () {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition,showError);
            var time = new Date();

            displayTime.innerHTML = time.getHours() + ":" + time.getMinutes() + ":" + time.getSeconds();
        }, 3000);

    } else {
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
}

function showPosition(position) {
    var latlon = position.coords.latitude+","+position.coords.longitude;

    var img_url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center="
    +latlon+"&markers=size:mid%7Ccolor:red%7C"+latlon+"&zoom=14&size=400x300&sensor=false";
    document.getElementById("mapholder").innerHTML = "<img src='"+img_url+"'>";
}

function showError(error) {
    switch(error.code) {
        case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
            x.innerHTML = "User denied the request for Geolocation."
            break;
        case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
            x.innerHTML = "Location information is unavailable."
            break;
        case error.TIMEOUT:
            x.innerHTML = "The request to get user location timed out."
            break;
        case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
            x.innerHTML = "An unknown error occurred."
            break;
    }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are using a static map.  To change it you have to reload it.  If you want to dynamically update a marker on a Google Map, use the Google Maps Javascript API v3.

Comment: As @geocodezip said, a map provided by Google's JavaScript API would be much better for this task. Is there a specific reason you're using a static map?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best bet is to use navigator.geolocation.watchPosition which calls a function only if the postion of the agent changes. So

1) you do not need to set a timer function to constantly refresh

2) the panning is handled by  map.panTo() in  [this sample](http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/Rsp22/) so that issue is addressed too.

3) the code below also uses the navigator.geolocation

```
<script>
var x = document.getElementById("demo");
function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(showPosition);
    } else {
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
}
function showPosition(position) {
    x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude +
    "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
}
</script>
```

Hope it all heped

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem like the questioner. The easiest solution is to just replace

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition,showError);
```

with

```
navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(showPosition,showError);
```

Now your current position in Maps is getting tracked/centered when you move.

Answer (score -1):

Updated to animate marker

Include script

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

HTML

```
   <button onclick="fly()">Fly</button>
   <div id="mapCanvas"></div>
```

JavaScript

```
Number.prototype.linearScale = function(r1, r2) {
    return (this - r1[0] ) * (r2[1] - r2[0] ) / (r1[1] - r1[0] ) + r2[0];
};
var start = [40.722283, -74.014893];
var end = [51.508742, -0.131836];
var center = [((end[0] - start[0]) / 2) + start[0], ((end[1] - start[1]) / 2) + start[1]]
var el = document.getElementById('mapCanvas');
var map = new google.maps.Map(el, {
    center : new google.maps.LatLng(center[0], center[1]),
    zoom : 2,
    mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    disableDefaultUI : true,
    panControl : false,
    zoomControl : false,
    mapTypeControl : false,
    scaleControl : false,
    streetViewControl : false
});
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position : (new google.maps.LatLng(start[0], start[1])),
    map : map
});

function fly() {
    var steps = 100;
    var h = setInterval(function() {
        marker.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(steps.linearScale([100, 0], [start[0], end[0]]), steps.linearScale([100, 0], [start[1], end[1]])));
        if ((steps--) == 0)
            clearInterval(h);
    }, 100);
};
```

[CodePen Here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vlBxF)

Update: Thanks to A-Tomy-k for marker.setPosition

Comment: Nice example. I would replace your last two code lines for: **marker.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(locs[0][0], locs[0][1]));** It avoids creating the marker again. Also doesn't needed the trigger(map, 'resize') call.

Comment: @tnt-rox My question was about displaying the current location and refreshing it smoothly!

Comment: @tnt-rox in my question I stated "How can I display the current location smoothly on the map without having to refresh the entire map ( unless necessary such as when the agent goes off the map and current location no longer exist on the map)". So the concern are 1) current location 2) refreshing it without flickering 3)moving the map itself if marker goes off the map. you picked specific example were both departure and destination are at the same time (and always ) in the map where no panning was needed!! nowhere you used current location, Please also run my code!!

Comment: @Cgraphics That would be in violation of Googles' terms of use. The logo must be displayed at all times.